# How to add month and year in input field using datepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I want to select month and year in the input field using datepicker.

Here I do not use any downloaded file or CDN to implement this. If it necessary,can anyone suggest a file to download. I do not want to implement CDN in my code.

```js
var startDate = new Date();
var fechaFin = new Date();
var FromEndDate = new Date();
var ToEndDate = new Date();

$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  minViewMode: 1,
  format: 'mm-yyyy'
}).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
  startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
  $('#datepicker2').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
});

$('#datepicker2').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  minViewMode: 1,
  format: 'mm-yyyy'
}).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
  FromEndDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
  FromEndDate.setDate(FromEndDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
  $('#datepicker1').datepicker('setEndDate', FromEndDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />


<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
  <h4><b>From Date :</b></h4>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f_date" id="datepicker1" required />
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
  <h4><b>To Date :</b></h4>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="t_date" id="datepicker2" required/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none;
}
```

and added/modified the onChange and onClose

```js
var startDate = new Date();
var fechaFin = new Date();
var FromEndDate = new Date();
var ToEndDate = new Date();

$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat: 'mm-yy',
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
  },
  onChange: function(selected) {
    startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
    $('#datepicker2').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
  }
})

$('#datepicker2').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat: 'mm-yy',
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
  },
  onChange: function(selected) {
    FromEndDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    FromEndDate.setDate(FromEndDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
    $('#datepicker1').datepicker('setEndDate', FromEndDate);
  }
})
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />


<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
  <h4><b>From Date :</b></h4>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f_date" id="datepicker1" required />
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
  <h4><b>To Date :</b></h4>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="t_date" id="datepicker2" required/>
</div>
```

As of August 2022, you need to download these 3 files I added to the snippet I made you

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Just right click and save!

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js

https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js

https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Comment: From where I can download these files? I want to use downloaded files in my code.That is why I asked@mplungjan

Comment: Also, I want to show only month and year.No need to show date@mplungjan

Comment: See updated script